# Dexterous Workspace

Tags: inverse-kinematics, dh-parameters, image-view

Can anyone please help me understand how I can get the dexterous workspace I know how to obtain the reachable workspace but in 3D I can't see the dexterous, anyone know of any tricks or tips? Would love if anyone could use either of the examples to help me understand, just want to see any differences between rotational and prismatic joints.

Sorry for any missing or undefined tags, thank you in advance.

[image]